# Is it possible to run a Java program without main()

Tags: java

I want to run a java program without using a **main method**. Is it possible? If so, could you give an example?

I just want to know what to say if an interviewer asks.

Comment: _I want to run java program without using main method_ why ?

Comment: To my understanding, this is not possible. What exactly are you trying to do? Please provide more context.

Comment: Better yet, *how*?  Java uses the class's `main` method to kickstart the app.

Comment: Java programs start executing at the main method. To say "I want to run a Java program without using the main method" is like saying "I want to run a race without ever crossing the start line".

Comment: Just before someone tried reservation project i just visit and tried to execute that program but it wasn't executed because there is no main method can u help me

Comment: @user3749978: If there is no `main` method, then that project is not an application; it's just a class (or a bunch of classes).  If it *is* an application, then by definition, somewhere within must be a class with a `main` method, and that's the class name you pass on the command line to start the program.

Comment: It is possible, but it depends on what you are doing. Look into applets (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/subclass.html for an example)

Comment: @Ranjith changing the question after it is marked as duplicate won't help you :) Ask a new question and remove irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 1):

> All Java programs that are run directly by the Java interpreter must
>   have a `main()`method.  Programs of this sort are often called
>   applications. It is possible to write programs that are not run
>   directly by the interpreter, but are dynamically loaded into some
>   other already running Java program. Examples are applets, which are
>   programs run by a web browser, and servlets, which are programs run by
>   a web server.

(O’Reilly, java in a nutshell)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer would be, No.

You need to create a main function where the control would be transfered when your application is first run. Othewise the JVM won't find a function to transfer the control and your app would not run.

Comment: "Othewise the OS won't find a function to transfer the control and your app would cause havoc".  It is not the OS which needs to find the function.  It is the JVM, and if you don't have a main method your app will not cause havoc.  It just won't run.

Comment: Yeah I didn't know that JVM thing. I have edited it now! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your Java program executing on the JVM will always begin it's execution with the main method. Chapter 12, section 1 (Execution, Java Virtual Machine Startup) of Java's language spec describes this in more detail.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1

> The Java Virtual Machine starts execution by invoking the method main of some specified class, passing it a single argument, which is an array of strings.